# MacOs libSystem package error

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite

Trying to install octave and getting such error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _map_fd
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/install_name_tool
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _map_fd
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/install_name_tool
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

I'm using OsX 10.10 according to the referencehttp://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X#Package_Managers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 3.2.6 is the last version of Xcode that supports building kernel extension for Mac OS X 10.4 and 10.5. However, running Xcode 3.2.6 on Mac OS X versions greater than 10.6 is unsupported and requires some tweaking.

Try workaround here:
https://github.com/bfleischer/map_fd

Comment: Octave isn't a kernel extension, though. You seem to have copied the description from that Github project without an eye to context…

Comment: Yes. You are right about copypasting. I thought user is discovering such exception every time during installing anything via homebrew. I've had such issue in the past and the workaround helped me

Comment: It works. Thanks for help. I am newbie here and don't pay attention whether was it copied from somewhere.